Physiology of fetal haemoglobin
So HbF has lower binding with HbA which helps increase it's affinity for oxygen. The physiological reason being that it helps HbF to snatch oxygen from HbA.
However, fetal cells are extremely active and dividing which means they should have greater oxygen demand than the mother.
As we see in this question, oxygen affinity must decrease but haemoglobin concentration should increase when there is greater demand, for best oxygen supply. 
How does the fetus cope with this?
And when HbF is slowly replaced by HbA in later parts of intrauterine life, how does fetus extract oxygen from mother?
My research:
I hadn't found much I could understand but article here says that HbA has higher affinity than HbF but 2,3-BPG helps in reducing affinity of HbA while having insignificant effect on HbF allowing it to snatch oxygen from maternal haemoglobin. So maybe the fetus produces extremely high conc. of 2,3-BPG so that even the adamant HbF is forced to bind to it and release oxygen?

@anongoodnurse Done

Great! I'll dig around re. HgbF when I have some time. :)
